# Registry autostart causes error "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Tags: c#, autostart

Adding program to registry:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", true);

key.SetValue("App", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App.exe");
key.Close();
```

and removing from registry:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

key.DeleteValue("App", false);
key.Close();
```

After starting the program needs to log in or that happens automatically, if I don't log out and close the program.

So, problems:

1. After booting the machine and starting program an error pops up with text "The underlying provider failed on Open".
2. When I fill authorization form and click log in everything is OK.

Maybe that happens because some Windows services like SQL Server are booting later than my program or something like that.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Your own conclusion could indeed be accurate; the solution in that case would be to add code to your application that waits for whatever other services it depends on to have started.
Have a look at this search on SO, to get started:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+running+processes